Почему не видит модуль pkg_resources?
При запуске процесса выскакивает ошибка, что система не может найти модуль pkg_resource, я проверил наличие setuptools и pkg_resources в папке (ОН существует, он там есть), подумал, что произошла ошибка и решил удалил setuptools

pip uninstall setuptools
а потом установил заново
pip install setuptools success

Установка прошла успешно, и при запуске процесса снова выскакивает та же ошибка и я не понимаю, что делать

Проще всего откатить Python до 3.11 (там возможно будет выскакивать предупреждение, что pkg_resources is deprecated as an API, но работать должно все равно). Или переписать код так, чтобы pkg_resources не использовалось.
